# Maven error with richfaces-showcase of RichFaces 4.3.1 Final

Tags: java, maven, richfaces, maven-3

I tried to run richfaces-showcase of RichFaces 4.3.1 Final. When I execute the command "mvn clean package" as readme.txt instructed I get a Maven error. The error text is as follows:

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building RichFaces Showcase 4.3.1.Final
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.137s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon May 06 14:31:42 CST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/60M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war
-plugin:2.1.1 (C:\Users\han59650\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-w
ar-plugin\2.1.1\maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): error in opening zip file -> [Help
1]
    org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginDescriptorParsingException: Failed to parse plugin
 descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (C:\Users\han596
50\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin\2.1.1\maven-war-plug
in-2.1.1.jar): error in opening zip file
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.extractPlu
ginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginD
escriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDes
criptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(D
efaultBuildPluginManager.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalc
ulator.setupMojoExecution(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalc
ulator.setupMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalc
ulator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalc
ulator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(Bu
ilderCommon.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
352)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:136)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.extractPlu
ginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:170)
    ... 25 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

My environment is:
Maven 3.0.5
JDK 1.6

Can anyone help me psl?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have corrupted file downloaded, delete this directory and let maven download it again

```
C:\Users\han59650\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin
```